# I'm able to hit my API for every request, but my POST request to create a new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, cors, react-redux

I'm working on authentication (using Knock) for my rails API and I can't hit my POST route to create a new user using a react client. I am able to hit this route in Postman and it successfully creates a new user. I can see I hit the route in postman from the terminal, but when I try it on my client I don't get any response in the terminal.

Things I've tried

1. Ensured client and server are running on different ports

   - I have my client on localhost:3000 and my server on localhost:3001
2. Made sure I have CORS set up

   - I am using the gem 'rack-cors' and have a cors initializer setup according to the docs for Rails 5. (I can include this file if you believe its needed)
   - I also have enabled CORS on my chrome web browser
3. Try another POST route

   - I am able to successfully log in on the client side (using a user's email/password I created in postman) and generate a JWT token using a POST route to my api
4. Made sure I am getting to the action creator from my container

   - I put a debugger in the action creator to make sure I am hitting it when I submit the form. I hit it and have all the relevant info I need (first name, last name, email, and password) to complete the request.

I think the problem lies somewhere in my userSignUpFetch action creator or in my user Controller.

Action creator that handle process of sending new user object to rails

```
export const userSignUpFetch = (user) => {
  const newUser = user
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/users`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept:"application/json",
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({user: user})
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(jresp => {
        dispatch(loginUserFetch({
          first_name: newUser.first_name,
          last_name: newUser.last_name,
          email: newUser.email,
          password: newUser.password})
        );
      })
      .catch((errors) => {
        dispatch(authFailure(errors))
      })
  };
}
```

My current Routes for auth in Rails

```
api_users      GET      /api/users(.:format)   api/users#index
               POST     /api/users(.:format)  api/users#create
api_user       GET      /api/users/:id(.:format) api/users#show
               PATCH    /api/users/:id(.:format) api/users#update
               PUT      /api/users/:id(.:format) api/users#update
               DELETE   /api/users/:id(.:format) api/users#destroy
api_user_token POST     /api/user_token(.:format) api/user_token#create
api_find_user  POST     /api/find_user(.:format) api/users#find
```

My Rails User Controller

```
class Api::UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update]

  def index
    @users = User.all
    render json: @users
  end

  def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
    if @user.valid? && @user.save
      render json: @user
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: 400
    end
  end

  def show
    render json: @user
  end

  def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      render json: @user
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: 400
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
  end

  def find
   @user = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email])
   if @user
     render json: @user
   else
     @errors = @user.errors.full_messages
     render json: @errors
   end
  end

  private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password)
  end

end
```

I'm expecting to see something like

Started POST "/api/users" for ::1 at 2019-05-28 17:56:41 -0500

in my terminal, but when I hit that action creator I don't get any response from my terminal running the server. I'm wondering if anybody has any suggestions on what to look for. Thanks.

**Update**

I believe it is something with my dispatch.

This below works, up until jresp.loginUserFetch

```
export const userSignUpFetch = user => {
  //Fetch request info
  const newUser = JSON.stringify({user: user})
  const userAuth = JSON.stringify({user})

  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: newUser
  }
  const fetchURL = `${API_URL}/users`

  return fetch(fetchURL, options)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(jresp => jresp.loginUserFetch({
        first_name: userAuth.first_name,
        last_name: userAuth.last_name,
        email: userAuth.email,
        password: userAuth.password}))
    .catch( err => {
      console.log('Request Failed:', err)
    })
}
```

**Update 2- Got it To work**

I imported fetch from cross fetch as well as cleaned it up a little, but it works as attended now which makes me believe I needed cross-fetch in the file.

```
export const userSignUpFetch = user => {
  //Fetch request info
  const newUser = JSON.stringify({user: user})

  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: newUser
  }
  const fetchURL = `${API_URL}/users`

  return dispatch => {
    return fetch(fetchURL, options)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(jresp => { dispatch(loginUserFetch({
        first_name: user.first_name,
        last_name: user.last_name,
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password})
        )
      })
      .catch( err => {
        console.log('Request Failed:', err)
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you see anything on your browser console?

Comment: When I submit the form I get nothing on the browser console also.

Comment: Does the code get into the `.then()` at all on the React side?

Comment: Put in a console.log to see and it does not

Comment: No luck testing with Postman or anything similar?